# How to store a Workbook name as a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have WorkbookA.xlsm and my code directly references "WorkbookA.xlsm"

When my workbook is distributed, not everybody leaves the name the same and it causes 'subscript out of range' errors.

How can I declare a workbook as a variable or similar? `thisworkbook.name`?

My product opens a separate workbook, pulls data from it, and then places it into my workbook - I was worried `thisworkbook` or similar might cause issues if more than one are open.

Comment: Yes; The current workbook (i.e. where you code lives) is `ThisWorkbook`, its name is `ThisWorkbook.Name`

Comment: otherwise you can just say "dim OrigWB as Workbook" and then "Set OrigWB = ActiveWorkbook" then just work with OrigWB instead of ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook. You'll just have to declare this before you open the other workbooks ;) and for the workbook that you open it would be the same but instead of "=ActiveWorkbook" it would be " = Workbooks.Open(*PathToYourWorkbook*)"

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub WorkingWithDataFromOtherWorkBook()

      'You can also Dim as Sheet and then set the sheet     
      Dim MasterWorkBook As Workbook
      Dim DataSourceWorkBook As Workbook

      Set MasterWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
      'Set DataSourceWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=" Full File Path Here")
      Set DataSourceWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\oosthjp\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")

      'Simple copy paste code below
      DataSourceWorkBook.Sheets("SheetReference").Range("SOMERANGE").Copy
      MasterWorkBook.Sheets("SheetReference").Range("SOMERANGE").Paste

      'Whatever other code you have goes here

 End Sub
```

Comment: Or remove all MasterWorkbook variables and use:
ThisWorkBook.Sheets("SheetReference").Range("SOMERANGE").Paste